# python pandas isin method?

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary 'wordfreq' like this:

```
{'techsmart': 30, 'paradies': 57, 'jobvark': 5000, 'midgley': 100, 'weisman': 2, 'tucuman': 1, 'amdahl': 2, 'frogfeet': 1, 'd8848': 1, 'jiaoyuwang': 1, 'walter': 19}
```

and I want to put the keys in a list if the value is more than 5 and also if the key is not in another dataframe 'df', and then adding them to a list called 'stopword':here is a df dataframe:

```
word    freq
1   paradies    1
5   tucuman 1
```

and here is the code I am using:

```
stopword = []
for k,v in wordfreq.items():
    if v >= 5:
        if k not in list_c:
             stopword.append((k))
```

Anybody knows how can I do the same thing with isin() method or more efficiently at least?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd load your dict into a df:

```
In [177]:

wordfreq = {'techsmart': 30, 'paradies': 57, 'jobvark': 5000, 'midgley': 100, 'weisman': 2, 'tucuman': 1, 'amdahl': 2, 'frogfeet': 1, 'd8848': 1, 'jiaoyuwang': 1, 'walter': 19}
df = pd.DataFrame({'word':list(wordfreq.keys()), 'freq':list(wordfreq.values())})
df
Out[177]:
    freq        word
0      1    frogfeet
1      1     tucuman
2     57    paradies
3      1       d8848
4   5000     jobvark
5    100     midgley
6      1  jiaoyuwang
7     30   techsmart
8      2     weisman
9     19      walter
10     2      amdahl
```

And then filter using `isin` against the other df (df_1 in my case) like this:

```
In [181]:

df[(df['freq'] > 5) & (~df['word'].isin(df1['word']))]
Out[181]:
   freq       word
4  5000    jobvark
5   100    midgley
7    30  techsmart
9    19     walter
```

So the boolean condition looks for freq values greater than 5 and also where the word is not in the other df using `isin` and invert the boolean mask `~`.

You can then now get a list easily:

```
In [182]:

list(df[(df['freq'] > 5) & (~df['word'].isin(df1['word']))]['word'])
Out[182]:
['jobvark', 'midgley', 'techsmart', 'walter']
```